# UnixTime to readable date

Tags: c++, date, time, unix-timestamp

What is the best way to convert UnixTime to a date?

Is there a function for it or an algorithm?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unix time is seconds since epoch (1970-01-01). Depending on what you mean, you can convert it to a `struct tm` with [localtime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) or convert it to a string with [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
char date[20];
strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%Y-%m-%d", tm);
```

---

As the manual to localtime states

> The return value points to a statically allocated
>   struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the
>   date and time functions.

This is what some refer to as data races. This happens when two or more threads call `localtime` simultaneously.

To protect from this, some suggest using `localtime_s`, which is a Microsoft only function. On POSIX systems, you should use `localtime_r` instead

> The localtime_r() function does the same,
>   but stores the data in a user-supplied struct.

Usage would look like

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm res;
localtime_r(&t, &res);
```

Comment: Thanks, but compiler says "localtime" is depreceated. Can I simply ignore it and use "#pragma warning(disable:4996)"?

Comment: @Mellnik: See [Are the time functions of MSVC thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278919/are-the-time-functions-of-msvc-thread-safe) for more info on that.

Comment: @Mellnik This is new to me. It seems to be a Microsoft Windows issue. In my environment (gcc 4.6.3) there's no such warning.

Comment: The problem is that localtime() can cause race conditions:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/

On Windows, consider localtime_s() instead (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386923/localtime-vs-localtime-s-and-appropriate-input-arguments).

Comment: What if the Epoch time you wish to convert isn't the current time but any other given time (example: 1464545562043 )?

Comment: I don't know, 1464545562043 is *way* beyond the year 2038 (somewhere around 1970 + 46440). But it is still inside the 64 bit limit, so it depends on the implementation (32/64 bit), including any implementation bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have the time in a `time_t`. First you need to convert that to a `struct tm`. You can do this with [`localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) or [`gmtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/), depending on whether you want to use the local timezone or GMT.

Then you can format that `struct tm` as a string with [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/). For example, to get a date like `2012-11-24` you'd use the format `"%Y-%m-%d"`.

Answer (score 1):

See also [Convert Unix/Linux time to Windows FILETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585583/convert-unix-linux-time-to-windows-filetime/41443329#41443329)

This function should convert from UnixTime into Windows SYSTEMTIME

```
SYSTEMTIME intChromeTimeToSysTime(long long int UnixTime)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER uLarge;
    uLarge.QuadPart = UnixTime;
    FILETIME ftTime;
    ftTime.dwHighDateTime = uLarge.HighPart;
    ftTime.dwLowDateTime = uLarge.LowPart;
    SYSTEMTIME stTime;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftTime, &stTime);
    return stTime;

}
```