# localtime vs localtime_s and appropriate input arguments

Tags: c++, localtime

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
```

This returns: warning C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead.

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime_s ( &rawtime );
```

When I change localtime to localtime_s I get: error C2660: 'localtime_s' : function does not take 1 arguments

Here is what I think is going on in the first block of code:

- create an empty time_t variable.
- create a pointer to timeinfo which is defined in ctime
- write the rawtime into a rawtime reference
- convert the rawtime into something meaningful to pedestrians

  1. Am I right?
  2. What second input parameter does localtime_s need?
  3. What's the worst that could happen if I just ignore the whole localtime safety issue.

Comment: yes, I found this immediately: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye(v=vs.80).aspx but I don't yet understand how to interpret these template/generic? descriptions of methods.  Much like I don't understand the syntax/symbols of general form wiki math articles.  struct tm* _tm and const time_t *time doesn't mean anything to me as far as what I'm really telling the method... though I wish it did.

Comment: Yes, I have some of those too.

Answer (score 70):

`localtime` returns a pointer to a statically allocated `struct tm`.

With localtime_s, you pass in a pointer to a struct tm, and `localtime_s` writes its result data into that, so your code would change from:

```
struct tm *timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
```

to something like:

```
struct tm timeinfo;
localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
```

This way, it's writing to *your* buffer instead of having a buffer of its own.

Comment: With those changes I get these errors: error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'errno_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\wchar.h(1120): could be 'tm &tm::operator =(const tm &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(tm, errno_t)'
error C2664: 'strftime' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'tm' to 'const tm *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO: That's clearly happening in code you haven't shown above, but it's probably because `timeinfo` is now a `struct tm` instead of a pointer, so where other functions use it, you'll need to change `timeinfo` to `&timeinfo`.

Comment: This line: &timeinfo = localtime_s ( &timeinfo, &rawtime ); Gives this error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'errno_t' to 'tm *'

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO: Reread the answer. `localtime` returns a pointer to a `struct tm` -- `localtime_s` does *not* (it returns an error number to tell you whether the conversion you requested succeeded or not).

Answer (score 8):

localtime_s is just a microsoft implementation of the localtime functon, you can safely keep using `locatime` becaue it's C++ ISO compliant and ony microsoft marked it as "deprecated". The localtime function itself isn't deprecated at all in the C++ world.

The `localtime_s` [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says that these parameters should be passed to it:

```
_tm 
Pointer to the time structure to be filled in.
 time 
Pointer to the stored time.
```

Comment: FWIW, the POSIX standard corrected function is `localtime_r`.  Works exactly the same, except the order of the two arguments is reversed.

Comment: `localtime_s` is part of the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) since C11.

Comment: @Pietro Only as part of the [optional Annex K](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K), which has *de facto* only been (poorly) implemented by Microsoft. Per [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations): "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Thank you for pointing this out. Just read on cppreference: "The implementation of localtime_s in Microsoft CRT is incompatible with the C standard since it has reversed parameter order."

Answer (score 8):

As [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) pointed out, `localtime` is not thread safe as well as several other time function. I wanted to know more about the subject and I found [a relevant blog post](http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/exploring-c11-part-2-localtime-and-time-again/) with a thoughrough explanation about that.

The quote below explains why `localtime`is not thread-safe:

> [...] localtime returns a pointer to a static buffer (std::tm*). Another thread can call the function and the static buffer could be overwritten before the first thread has finished reading the content of the struct std::tm*.