# get current date with localtime_s

Tags: c++

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm *now = localtime(&t);
```

With the code above, I can simply get the date like this:

```
int yearNow = (now.tm_year + 1900), monthNow = (now.tm_mon + 1), dayNow = now.tm_mday
```

but Visual Studio 2015 gives me error on `localtime`, ask me to use `localtime_s` instead. Below is my code with using `localtime_s`:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm now;
localtime_s(&now, &rawtime);
```

But the problem is, how do I get the actual current year, month, day in `int`?
I print the variable with this code: `cout << now.tm_year << " " << now.tm_mon << " " << now.tm_mday;`
but the output is `-1 -1 -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `time_t` variable should be initialized with `time(&rawtime)` such that `localtime_s` can use it to properly fill out the `struct`.  Much like your very first line `time_t t = time(0)`, it's required that you initialize the variable with the `time` function and pass it a null parameter (0) or a pointer to the variable (&rawtime).

Unfortunately allocating a `time_t` var within memory does not automatically calculate the time since Epoch.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386923/localtime-vs-localtime-s-and-appropriate-input-arguments) a question that addresses the same problem, except it has an example of the code you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

What I found from a different question [How do you get the current time of day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296920/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-of-day)

the code below will give you a string for the date. you should be able to split this and convert it to an int.

> DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay gives it to you as a TimeSpan (from midnight).
>   DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") gives it to you as a string.
>   DateTime reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime

many thanks to Mark Brackett for this answer