# Converting system time int to formatted time string?

Tags: c++, windows, time

I am writing a tool for a game and I am reading it's memory to retrieve the system time of the messages sent to the game's chat. That time is in the format of an integer containing the current system time as `1429959524`, for example. How could I convert this value to a formatted time string as `HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS`? I can't figure out a simple way to do this.

Comment: What's the language? And what did you try?

Comment: C++ using the Windows API. I have tried to do this using the time.h library and the time_t and timeinfo structure but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnixTime to readable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536886/unixtime-to-readable-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current time and date in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `<ctime>` header you can get the time formatted nicely in a string by using `strftime`

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer[10];
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
strftime(buffer,10,"%I:%M:%S",timeinfo);
std::string str(buffer);
```

Orifinally explained at [Current date and time as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357999/current-date-and-time-as-string)