# How to convert a datetime string with milliseconds to UNIX timestamp

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I have the following string

```
2013-04-12 16:00:15.041
```

What is the C++ way to convert this string into a 64bit UNIX timestamp? Most question on here deal with only having the timestamp until seconds but in my case I also need to include the milliseconds.

Comment: seconds * 1000 + milliseconds.

Comment: A Unix timestamp is "the number of **seconds** that have elapsed since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC". It doesn't have **milliseconds** precision, so you are going to lose the milliseconds no matter how you convert the string.

Comment: Does that string represent UTC or a specific local time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnixTime to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536886/unixtime-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string into its components and construct a `std::chrono::time_point`.  In C++20, you will have the `utc_clock` in [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono), that is, a [`utc_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock), or else `std::chrono::local_t`.  In C++11 and up, you have [`std::chrono::system_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock).

There’s sort of a chicken-and-egg problem in converting the broken-down-time into STL time objects, though: usually, doing that gives you your answer with just the C library.  You can use [`std::get_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), on an `istringstream` if necessary, to convert your string to a `tm` and the C standard library function [`mktime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html#) to convert the `tm` to a `time_t`, which you can then pass to `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t()`to convert to a `std::chrono::time_point`—except that, on UNIX/Linux, `time_t` is already a UNIX timestamp!

Your example has no time zone specified, so you might or might not need to do time-zone conversion.

The `utc_clock` uses the [same Epoch as POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16), January 1, 1970, so the `time_since_epoch()` member function of `utc_time`/`time_point` gives you the answer as a `std::chrono::duration`.  If you are using `system_clock` instead, the Epoch is implementation-defined (but almost always the same Epoch, too), so you will want to find a `time_point` for 12:00 AM January 1, 1970, and subtract it from the `time_point` you calculate to get a duration.  You can convert this duration, call it `moment`, into seconds with `std::chrono::seconds(moment).count()`.  You can then convert to `int64_t` or `uint64_t` (from `<cstdint>`) if you want to be sure to have an exactly 64-bit value.

There are a [few different UNIX time formats](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html), but if you want to convert your time in milliseconds into a C/POSIX `timespec` with nanoseconds, rather than the obsolete formats in `<sys/time.h>`, set `.tv_nsec` to the number of milliseconds times one million, or convert from `std::chrono::milliseconds` to `std::chrono::nanoseconds`.

If the purpose of this is to work with filesystem timestamps, you might want [`std::filesystem::file_time_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type).

Comment: "*If you are on UNIX or Linux, you can use `getdate()` to convert your string to a `tm`*" - C++11 and later has [`std::get_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) to read a formatted date/time string from a `std::istream` into a `tm`. You can use `std::istringstream` for that stream, and `std::get_time()` is more flexible than `gettime()`