# Why is there no C++11 threadsafe alternative to std::localtime and std::gmtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, c++-chrono

In C++11 you still have to use `std::localtime` and `std::gmtime` as indirection to print a `std::chrono::time_point`. These functions are not safe to use in a multithreaded environment as introduced with C++11 because they return a pointer to an internal static struct. This is especially annoying since C++11 introduced the convenient function `std::put_time` which is nearly unusable for the same reason.

Why is this so fundamental broken or do I overlook something?

Comment: Wow, those functions are almost as well designed as `strtok`.

Comment: "C++ programming should not be easy" I suppose this still the overriding philosophy - you need something you write something yourself unless it is an absolute bare bone minimum.

Comment: I fully agree to your rant. It would have been easy to implement std::localtime() as a wrapper around GLIBC's localtime_r(). But now it is broken in the standard.

Answer (score 17):

According to [N2661](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm), the paper that added `<chrono>`:

> This paper does not offer calendrical services except for a minimal
>   mapping to and from C's `time_t`.
>
> > As this paper does not propose a date/time library, nor specify epochs, it also does not address leap seconds. However, a date/time
> >     library will find this to be an excellent foundation on which to
> >     build.
>
> This paper does not propose a general purpose physical quantities
>   library.
>
> > This paper proposes a solid foundation that, in the future, could provide a compatible starting point for a general physical units
> >     library. While such a future library might take any of several forms,
> >     the present proposal stops well short of actually being a physical
> >     units library. This proposal is time-specific, and continues to be
> >     motivated by the time-related needs of the threading library.
>
> The major goal of this proposal is to satisfy the needs of the
>   standard library threading API in a manner which is easy to use, safe
>   to use, efficient, and flexible enough to not be obsolete 10 or even
>   100 years from now. Every feature contained in this proposal is here
>   for a specific reason with practical use cases as motivation. Things
>   that fell into the category of "cool", or "that sounds like it might
>   be useful", or "very useful but not needed by this interface" have not
>   been included. Such items might appear in other proposals, and
>   possibly target a TR.

Note that the major goal of `<chrono>` is "to satisfy the needs of the standard library threading API", which does not require calendar services.

Comment: Ok,this may explain the design chose a bit, apart from introducing `std::put_time` without a save, platform independent way of using it.

Comment: @TNA Well, it was intended as a [replacement for `strftime`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2071.html), which also needs a `tm *`.

Comment: In my opinion, if you replace a C-function by a C++ function it should be consistent in a way, that you don't need unsafe C-Functions to use it. There is no save, platform independent way to get a `tm` so all functions using a `tm` are unusable with C++11 apart from some special cases. There is no standard way around it.

Comment: The real reason is that anything time related was **incredibly** controversial on the committee, and it was a a squeaker just to get `<chrono>` standardized.  Had we attempted calendrical services as well, C++11 would have been named C++14 at least.  Here http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/date.html is a post-C++11 calendrical proposal that the committee hated.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I can understand not supporting complex calendar related operations. But it doesn't explain why it returns a reference to a global mutable variable, instead of accepting it as a by-reference parameter or returning it by-value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos:  Because the `localtime`/`gmtime` API is older than bits. ;-)

Comment: The link I give above to the "calendrical proposal that the committee hated" has died.  Here is a fresh version of that old link:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date.html  Additionally here is a much improved "version 2" of that library:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html  Here is the github-based implementation currently composed of 3 distinct (but related libraries): https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Damn, someone's ***really*** overcomplicated this. His arguments about `date(m,d,y)` being ambigious with `date(d,m,y)` are mostly invalid anyways, because we already have a perfectly good standard for dates (ISO 8601), and we could adapt that ordering and use `date(y,m,d)`. I'm sure everyone could agree on that (and even if not, it's an API, not a plaintext input). Bonus points in that a potential overload that adds time only adds arguments *at the end* (as in, `date(y,m,d,hour,min,sec)`).

Answer (score 16):

`localtime` and `gmtime` have internal storage that is static, which means they are not threadsafe (we have to return a pointer to a data structure, so it either has to be allocated dynamically, a static value or a global value - since allocating dynamically would leak memory, that is not a reasonable solution, meaning that it has to be a global or static variable [theoretically, one could allocate and store in TLS, and make it threadsafe that way]).

Most systems do have threadsafe alternatives, but they are not part of the standard library. For example, Linux/Posix has `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r`, which takes an extra parameter for the result. See for example
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/gmtime.html

Similarly, Microsoft libraries have `gmtime_s`, which is also re-entrant and works in a similar way (passing in the output parameter as an input). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3stkd9be.aspx

As to why the standard C++11 library doesn't use these functions? That you'd have to ask the people who wrote that specification - I expect it's portability and convenience, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Note that `localtime` and `gmtime` in Microsoft's Visual C Runtime do use TLS and are threadsafe. (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2278919/25507).) `gmtime_s`'s purpose is security (adding parameter validation), not reentrancy (although the fact that it takes an output parameter lets it also work well for this).

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to use a [free, open-source 3rd party library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), here is a way to print `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` in UTC:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";
}
```

This is a thread-safe alternative to `std::gmtime` using modern C++ syntax.

For a modern, thread-safe `std::localtime` replacement, you need this closely related [higher level timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) and the syntax looks like this:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now()) << "\n";
}
```

Both of these will output with whatever precision your `system_clock` supports, for example:

```
2016-07-05 10:03:01.608080 EDT
```

(microseconds on macOS)

These libraries go far beyond a `gmtime` and `localtime` replacement.  For example, do you want to see the current date in the Julian calendar?

```
#include "julian.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << julian::year_month_day(date::floor<date::days>(system_clock::now())) << "\n";
}

2016-06-22
```

How about the current GPS time?

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";
    std::cout << gps_clock::now() << " GPS\n";
}

2016-07-05 14:13:02.138091 UTC
2016-07-05 14:13:19.138524 GPS
```

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r0.html

**Update**

The "date.h" and "tz.h" libraries are now in the draft C++2a specification, with very minor changes, and where we hope 'a' is '0'.  They will live in the header `<chrono>` and under `namespace std::chrono` (and there will not be a `date namespace`).

Comment: Sorry, but you first example is wrong: std::cout << system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";  first of all, it will not compile, second it is not in UTC (unless your computer is set to be on UTC timezone)

Comment: @Tadzys: All examples above are complete minimal programs that were tested prior to posting using the referenced libraries.  Second:  the epoch of `system_clock` is unspecified.  But the de facto standard among all three implementations of it is that it is tracking Unix Time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  I am attempting to get this current practice standardized: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r1.html

Comment: sorry, my bad, didn't realise that tz.h had overloaded << operator for time_point struct, and yes, I was wrong on my second point as well (that might explain my bug  that I am having :)

Comment: @Tadzys:  Perhaps these libraries can help with the bug you're having. :-)  Or if they don't, perhaps I can help anyway.

Comment: The Boost ptime library also has functions to turn a Unix file time into a sensible date/time, including printing it, and is probably a lot more widely used than this one.

Answer (score 5):

There is no threadsafe alternative to `std::localtime` and `std::gmtime` because you didn't propose one and marshal it through the entire standardization process.  And neither did anyone else.

`chrono`s only calendar code is code that wraps existing `time_t` functions.  Standardizing or writing new ones was outside of the domain of the `chrono` project.  Doing such standardization would require more time, more effort, and add more dependencies.  Simply wrapping each `time_t` function was simple, had few dependencies, and quick.

They focused their effort narrowly.  And they succeeded at what they focused on.

I encourage you to start working on `<calendar>` or joining such an effort to create a robust calendaring API for `std`.  Good luck and godspeed!

Answer (score 3):

As others had mentioned, there is really no threadsafe convenience and portable time formatting approach in any available C++ standard, but there is some archaic preprocessor technique I found usable (thanks to Andrei Alexandrescu at [CppCon 2015](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Presentations/Declarative%20Control%20Flow/Declarative%20Control%20Flow%20-%20Andrei%20Alexandrescu%20-%20CppCon%202015.pdf) slide 17 & 18):

```
std::mutex gmtime_call_mutex;

template< size_t For_Separating_Instantiations >
std::tm const * utc_impl( std::chrono::system_clock::time_point const & tp )
{
    thread_local static std::tm tm = {};
    std::time_t const time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( tp );
    {
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > ul( gmtime_call_mutex );
        tm = *std::gmtime( &time );
    }
    return &tm;
}


#ifdef __COUNTER__
#define utc( arg ) utc_impl<__COUNTER__>( (arg) )
#else
#define utc( arg ) utc_impl<__LINE__>( (arg) )
#endif
```

Here we declare function with `size_t` template argument and returning pointer to static member `std::tm`. Now each call of this function with different template argument create a new function with brand new static `std::tm` variable. If `__COUNTER__` macro is defined, it should be replaced by incremented integer value each time it is used, otherwise we use `__LINE__` macro and in this case better to be sure that we do not call macro `utc` twice in one line.

Global `gmtime_call_mutex` protect non-threadsafe `std::gmtime` call in each instantiation, and at least in Linux shouldn't be a performance problem as lock acquiring is firstly performed as running around spinlock, and in our case should never end up with real thread lock.

`thread_local` ensures that different threads running same code with `utc` calls will still working with different `std::tm` variables.

Example of usage:

```
void work_with_range(
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point from = {}
        , std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to = {}
        )
{
    std::cout << "Will work with range from "
         << ( from == decltype(from)()
              ? std::put_time( nullptr, "beginning" )
              : std::put_time( utc( from ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
            )
         << " to "
         << ( to == decltype(to)()
              ? std::put_time( nullptr, "end" )
              : std::put_time( utc( to ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
            )
         << "."
         << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that this would not protect against concurrent external use of gmtime or localtime in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Boost: not entirely sure if this is thread safe, but it seems so:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

std::wstring stamp = boost::posix_time::to_iso_wstring(
    boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time());
std::wstring stamp = boost::posix_time::to_iso_wstring(
    boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time());
```

See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html