# ways to record time in C++

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

What is the most adequate way to record time in C++ (*not* time elapsed but time)

I am now trying something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

    int main ()
    {

      using namespace std::chrono;
      high_resolution_clock::time_point t1= high_resolution_clock::now();

      time_t tt=system_clock::to_time_t(t1);
      std::cout<<"Right now it is: " << ctime(&tt)<<std::endl;

    }
```

but I see that this requires (or I am understanding it wrong??) that we convert from `chrono` to the the C way of timing with `to_time` so doesn't defeat the point of using `chrono`?

The usual examples I found while searching are about elapsed time, but I am wondering about just recording time since I am not that familiar with C++11

Comment: While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25618702/501250) is different from yours, the answers may apply here as well.

Comment: C++20 has features to enable decomposing a `system_clock` time point to its date and time components, but no standard library implementation implements them yet.  See [P0355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html).

Comment: C++20 will also have features for formatting a `system_clock` time point to a string using `std::format` and a `strftime`-like format string, but likewise no standard library has implemented those features yet.  See [P0645](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html)/[P1361](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1361r2.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

As of C++17 `std::chrono` has no facilities to easily decompose a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` into its calandar date and wall clock time other than to convert the `time_point` to a `time_t` and use the date/time formatting functionality inherited from C.

It's *posible* to do it using only `std::chrono`, but not simple.  For instance something like this can get the wall clock time from a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`:

```
std::string time_of_day(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time_point)
{
    using days = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>;
    auto midnight = std::chrono::floor<days>(time_point);
    auto time_since_midnight = time_point - midnight;
    auto hours = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::hours>(time_since_midnight);
    auto minutes = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::minutes>(time_since_midnight - hours);
    auto seconds = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(time_since_midnight - minutes - hours);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << hours.count() << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << minutes.count() << ":" << seconds.count();
    return oss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d9600ea1d9e058d)

It's not simple at all, and I'm sure there are corner cases I've neglected, but it works using only `std::chrono` facilities.

---

C++20 will introduce a couple of ways to do this more easily.  At time of writing no standard library implementation has implemented either of them though.

---

First of all, if you want the full date/time, there will be an overloaded [`operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/operator_ltlt) that will format and print that for you:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
```

---

If you want just the date or time part of the `time_point`, [`std::chrono::day_month_year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day), [`std::chrono::time_of_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_of_day), and friends can be used to decompose the `time_point`.

For instance, the above `time_of_day` function could be done much more simply like this:

```
std::chrono::time_of_day time_of_day(const std::chrono::sytem_clock::time_point& time_point)
{
    auto midnight = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(time_point);
    return std::chrono::time_of_day{time_point - midnight};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

See [P3055](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html) for more info.

---

The other method is the new [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) family of functions.  There will be a [`std::formatter` specialization for `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter) that will let you format a `time_point` to a string using a `strftime`-like format string.  For instance, the output of the following will be very similar (if not the same) as the previous two `time_of_day` functions:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{%T}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

See [P0645](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html) and [P1361](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1361r2.pdf) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`auto t1 = system_clock::now();` is the fix

time_point is

```
template<
    class Clock,
    class Duration = typename Clock::duration
> class time_point;
```

and `system_clock::to_time_t` wants `time_point<system_clock>` type, but you provide completly different type `time_point<high_resolution_clock>`

Comment: On some implementations (notably libstdc++ and sometimes libc++), `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is an alias for `std::chrono::system_clock`.

Comment: yes, like gcc's libstdc++, but author didn't specify compiler and library

Answer (score 0):

read the Note under this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Notes

The high_resolution_clock is not implemented consistently across different standard library implementations, and its use should be avoided. It is often just an alias for std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock, but which one it is depends on the library or configuration. When it is a system_clock, it is not monotonic (e.g., the time can go backwards). For example, for gcc's libstdc++ it is system_clock, for MSVC it is steady_clock, and for clang's libc++ it depends on configuration.

Generally one should just use std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock directly instead of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock: use steady_clock for duration measurements, and system_clock for wall-clock time.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto nowTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto tt = system_clock::to_time_t(nowTime);
    std::cout << "Right now it is: " << ctime(&tt) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best performance way is :

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t get_time_us() {
  struct timeval tv {0, 0};
  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  return tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec; // microsecond
}
uint64_t t0 = get_time_us();
// do_something
uint64_t t1 = get_time_us();
int time_cost = t1 - t0;
```

and for C++11:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2
t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// do_something
t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
int time_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); // ms
// int time_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count(); // us
```

for boost:

```
#include <date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
boost::posix_time::ptime t1(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
// do_something
boost::posix_time::ptime t2(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
boost::posix_time::time_duration diff(t2 - t1);
int micro_sec = diff.total_microseconds();
```

Comment: Isn't the fastest something using `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` ?